# Remove Widgets On Component End Overlap

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

I have a problem where I want a widget to appear when entering an area with a box collision, and then disappear when exiting. The part where it appears works fine, but I'm having difficulty making it disappear upon exit. I can make it work using "Remove All Widgets," but I don't want to use that because it affects my other widgets that need to remain active. How can I achieve this without using "Remove All Widgets"?

Widget will be killed but only mentioned one after leaving box component.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend “remove from parent”, like this :

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsUe2.png)